# ShowDialog Method in the Task

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using a thread and a Dispatcher event in my WPF application. In this I am using the ShowDialog() method to open the new window mywindow. I want to execute the loadData() method in the "continuewith" event only after the mywindow dialog closes. How can I do that? Right now the LoadData method executes before closing the mywindow dialog.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( new Action( () =>
  {
    Window mywindow = new Window();
    mywindow.ShowDialog();
  } ) );
}.ContinueWith( ( test ) =>
{
  LoadData();
} ) );
```

Comment: why are you using Thread to show the window...? It doesn't make any sense. This should be enough... Window mywindow = new Window();
mywindow.ShowDialog();

Task.StartNew( () =>{
LoadData();
});

Answer (score 2):

You are doing `asynchronous call` on UI dispatcher using [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) hence task gets completed even before waiting for dialog window to show up.

You should do `synchronous call` using [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which won't let task to be complete unless dialog window is open.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
   {
        Window mywindow = new Window();
        mywindow.ShowDialog();
   }
```

---

On a sidenote i think in question you wrongly pasted `Thread`, it should be `Task` instead.

```
        Task thread =Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                SecondaryWindow mywindow = new SecondaryWindow(new VM());
                mywindow.ShowDialog();
            }));
        }).ContinueWith((test) =>
        {
            LoadData();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use synchronous call instead of asynchronous call using Invoke. this will be call LoadData method.